# Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: php, cakephp

I am a trainee now. I am continue doing a a project left by last semester trainee. I found out he did a code as below :

```
 $auth = $this->Auth->User();
    if(!empty($auth)) {
        $auth['User']['is_admin'] = $this->inGroup('admin');
```

Can anyone teach me how to avoid this error ? Thank you.

Comment: What **is** the error, exactly?

Comment: He posted the error as the question title: "Cannot use string offset as an array"

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array, the $auth is a string. Someone told me string cannot be used this way, and I don't know why the last trainee did like this. I just continue his project, and I am still figuring how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `$auth` is an array.

```
 if(!empty($auth) && is_array($auth) && isset($auth['User'])) {
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, although I don't really understand, but the fatal error is now gone, it proceeded to next error " AclNode::node() - Couldn&#039;t find Aro node identified by &quot;Array ( [Aro0.model] =&gt; User [Aro0.foreign_key] =&gt; 2 ) &quot; "

Answer (score 1):

the error indicates that you parse string into array expected function

eg.

```
$this->inGroup(array('admin')); //check out its function definition for valid parameters.
```